# Use jQuery $ inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would use an expression like this

```
$("a[href*='2']").offset().left
```

but for iframe's elements ...

I tried this:

```
$("#inside-slider").contents().attr("a[href*='2']").offset().left
```

but nothing.

(inside-slider is my iframe's id)

Comment: Is the URL of the `iframe` in the same domain? If not, you can't (due to security restrictions in all modern web browsers) and this question should be closed as the 1000th exact duplicate of this problem.

Comment: yes is in the same domain ... you could link me the solution? i have searched but without result ... sorry :(

Comment: did you link your library inside the iframe page you're calling?

Comment: @Cabba, if it is in the same domain then it's not a duplicate (that I know of).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
$("#inside-slider").contents().attr("a[href*='2']").offset().left
```

Should be:

```
$("#inside-slider").contents().find("a[href*='2']").offset().left
```

You want to use `.find`, not `.attr`.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your code inside the page you are filling your I frame with but you will have to include the jquery library in it again.